# How can I compile C# code on Linux terminal?

Tags: c#, compilation

I'm starting learning C#, but I have no idea how I can compile my code using terminal. I searched the internet, but nothing helped me. I'm tryed to use `gmcs` and `csc` and nothing helped. So, how can I compile C# file using linux terminal?

Comment: may this help you? http://legendminds.in/how-to-run-net-core-console-app-on-linux/

Comment: No, i have no command "dotnet" and I can't install it with "apt install dotnet"

Comment: Have a look at how to [install .net sdk via linux package managers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/install/linux-package-manager-ubuntu-1910).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to compile a C# file, you need to have dotnet installed, here is a link with the info on how to install it. [Dotnet](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/install/linux-package-manager-ubuntu-1910)
Then you go to where the file is and put dotnet run  without <>
Although it is highly recommended that you create a project first and paste your code into the Program.cs file. This way you will avoid unnecessary headaches.

Comment: I did as you said and I get an error at startup dotnet: "Failed to complete because the specified command or the specified file was not found." I used: "dotnet file.cs"

Comment: is dotnet run file.cs

Answer (score 1):

https://www.mono-project.com/download/stable/#download-lin

Install mono.

And then in the console: **csc 'location of a .cs file'**

To run it: **mono 'location of the compiled exe'**

Comment: When i using csc I get an error: Syntax error: illegal atomic form: () inside expression `(string ...)'. I'm used "csc hello.cs" and get it

Comment: https://www.mono-project.com/docs/getting-started/mono-basics/
You mean this?

Comment: Yes, I mean this

Comment: WinForms Hello World or Console Hello World? Which one you tried to compile?

Comment: Console Hello World